# Unable to retrieve bestModel using Grid search

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, grid-search

I am using below code to get the best fit for a regression model and getting an error:

```
# Creating parameter grid
params = ParamGridBuilder()

# Adding grids for two parameters
params = params.addGrid(regression.regParam, [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0]) \
               .addGrid(regression.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])

# Building the parameter grid
params = params.build()
print('Number of models to be tested: ', len(params))

# Creating cross-validator
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, estimatorParamMaps=params, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=5)

from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder, TrainValidationSplit, CrossValidator
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator

# Get the best model from cross validation
best_model = cv.bestModel
```

And the error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-449-f7d43e2cf76b> in <module>
  3 
  4 # Get the best model from cross validation
 ----> 5 best_model = cv.bestModel
  6 
  7 # Look at the stages in the best model

AttributeError: 'CrossValidator' object has no attribute 'bestModel'
```

The CrossValidator used for getting the best model params isn't returning the trained model!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first fit and assign the CV model, before accessing the `bestModel` attribute; adapting the example from the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.tuning.CrossValidator):

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

dataset = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(Vectors.dense([0.0]), 0.0),
     (Vectors.dense([0.4]), 1.0),
     (Vectors.dense([0.5]), 0.0),
     (Vectors.dense([0.6]), 1.0),
     (Vectors.dense([1.0]), 1.0)] * 10,
    ["features", "label"])

lr = LogisticRegression()
grid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.maxIter, [0, 1]).build()
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator,
    parallelism=2)
```

Asking for `cv.bestModel` at this stage will give

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-388275196191991> in <module>
----> 1 cv.bestModel

AttributeError: 'CrossValidator' object has no attribute 'bestModel'
```

as in your case.

Fit and assign first:

```
cvModel = cv.fit(dataset)
cvModel.bestModel
# result:
LogisticRegressionModel: uid = LogisticRegression_f9c9ea282e32, numClasses = 2, numFeatures = 1
```